# "silent" health check with ansible

Tags: ansible

In an ansible role to deploy docker container I'm using uri module to access the healthy check of the container afterwearts it is delivered:

```
  - name: Health, readiness and info check
    uri:
      url: '{{ item.url }}'
      status_code: '{{ item.code }}'
      return_content: no
    ignore_errors: '{{ item.ignore }}'
    retries: '{{ item.retries }}'
    delay: '{{ item.delay }}'
    register: result
    until: item.code | default(200) | int == result.status
    with_items:
      - '{{ http_check }}'
    when: http_check is defined
```

In case of how much retries it will be needed to get healthy status for one container I get this output by exec a play:

```
FAILED - RETRYING: Health, readiness and info check (3 retries left).
```

Is there a way to "switch off" that output for retrying and just getting the end result?

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: might be possible, if you are willing to use a different [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) and eventually write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Miss understood the question totally, check this URL might help, also you can set no_log parameter, but it will mark the task as failed anyways. The correct way  will be a custom callback plugin (That escapes my knowledge at the moment)
[Reddit post console output](https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/eo604j/method_to_hide_failed_retrying_in_console_output/)

Comment: thx for your answer. I've switched on `return_content: yes` but I can still see the output `FAILED - RETRYING: Health, readiness and info check (5 retries left).` So doesn't seem to works as aspected.

Comment: Can you post how you try to access the data? I think the problem is there.

Comment: I don't want to access the data. I just wanna get rid of the retry messages in play output. Not more. Maybe you misunerstand my question?

Comment: Oh! for sure i misunderstood it, you cant do it easily. One approach I'm seeing you can  do is write no_log parameter, but it will still mark the task as failed I(if it fails ) il let a reference link is used some months ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/eo604j/method_to_hide_failed_retrying_in_console_output/